# Can turning off the breaker box damage it

Tags: electrical-panel

I was removing a Jacuzzi and the homeowner turned off all the breakers for the house (even though I only needed one turned off). I don't know whether she flipped the master switch or the subsidiary switches first but she did both. Later we turned everything on but the jacuzzi breakers. I was fine working outside with my reciprocating saw plugged into the house. I remove the special secondary fuse then I cut the jacuzzi wires, put plastic hats on the ends and wrap them in tape.

Later she finds that most of the plugs and lights in the house no longer work. What happened?

Comment: Are the breakers all back on? Any GFCI outlets that may have tripped with the power cycle? Need to reset any GFCI outlets? Those are all my first guesses.

Comment: maybe one of the main breakers failed, so you are missing power to 1/2 of the breaker panel

Comment: All the breakers but the jacuzzi breaker is on and she said she pressed all the GFCI reset buttons. Is each column of the breaker box going to be on the same leg?

Comment: Nope, alternating legs is most common.

Comment: What make and model is the panel that is involved in this?

Comment: I'm no longer there and can't see the breaker. Is it reasonably common to find a cheap breaker box that can't take a turn off to damage it or is it more likely that I singlehandedly messed up half the house by working on the jacuzzi (without causing bangs, smoke, or electrocuting myself)?

Comment: @ClintEastwood works like [this.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc)

Comment: Certain obsolete panels might have a problem.  It would be very unusual for a routine turnoff to prevent turn back on.  It could be the house has other electrical issues, just look at the former jacuzzi wiring lol...